# visual svn server with iis 7

Tags: svn, iis-7, repository, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am developing a project in `php` with svn subversioning system using `Visual SVN` server.

I have some websites in my private webserver(`IIS 7`) and I would like to let the trunk folder of the project in my repository be accessible via `IIS`.

is that possible to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really asked* about

"How to publish my code from repository in order to use it inside IIS-powered site"

You have to read about Subversion post-commit hooks, which can do any operations with data in repo, in your case - `svn export` to the root of your IIS-site, or, if you'll prefer to see site-root as Working Copy `svn up`

Comment: but doesn't the export command export the files in a local folder? I need to "svn export" the current trunk folder server side. but I'm in the client side.

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo - you have to read `svn help export` also, because `export` command has two forms, and 1-st is you case `export [-r REV] URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]`. From help-text: "Exports a clean directory tree from the repository specified by URL, at revision REV if it is given, otherwise at HEAD, into PATH." In your case, if repository is on the same <strike>FS</strike>host, as target, just use file:/// access-protocol

Comment: the repository is NOT on the same host. it's remote.

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo - doesn't matter, export + scp|ftp|rsync

Answer (score 3):

VisualSVN installs Apache httpd as a web server.

I don't believe you can install [Subversion to work under IIS](https://superuser.com/a/306160/114804). However, that was an answer from 18 months ago, so things might have changed, but I doubt it. I did find a Google Code project called [RocketSVN](https://code.google.com/p/rocket-svn-server/), but it looks like it was deprecated.

I found a commercial package at [SVNISapi](http://www.svnisapi.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to create a `.bat` file server side that would be executed every day/week.

here's the simple batch file

```
svn export -r HEAD file:///C:/repo/proj C:\root\proj --force
```

remove dir 'cause the export command doesn't allow to overwrite the existent folder.

the `C:\root\` is the `iis7` folder.